# Is it possible to use Google Search Image API or Custom Search API for reverse image lookup?

Tags: javascript, php, google-custom-search, google-image-search

I am developing a web app, that has a feature of uploading the images from computer, user's google drive account or dropbox account. I need to implement the feature of Google image Search.That is, once user uploads images from any of these above mentioned sources, google image search should help me to look up for the images similar to the uploaded images. For that I go through the Google Image Search API(which is deprecated) and Custom Search API. Going through the documents of these two APIs and also going through some of the similar kind of questions on stackoverflow, I found that none of these Google API supports reverse Image search. So I want to know is that possible to search for the uploaded images using reverse google image search using either javascript, jQuery, PHP or all ?
I tried the following way as mentioned in their documentation, just for the demo.

**index.php**

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '0175600182164289:bbjtp1p';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:searchbox></gcse:searchbox>
<gcse:searchresults defaultToImageSearch="true"></gcse:searchresults>
```

Also I want to know, Is there a way to know the IP address/Site Owner for all the results we are getting.